# Update query in ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I want to update the ContentProvider through Update query but it always returns error, I unable to recognize the exact reason for not running update query.

**Error Log:**

```
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE chats SET media_type=?,jid=?,pid=?,sender_name=?,is_upload=?,read=?,from_me=?,date=?,message=?,sender_ph_no=? WHERE jid=amit@chat.spectratech.in and sender_name=sanat@chat.spectratech.in and date=1450252580946
```

**Code:**

```
private void updateChatMessageToDB(int direction, String JID, String message, int delivery_status, long ts, String packetID, String group_chat_sender_name, String group_chat_sender_ph_no, String media_type) {
        android.content.ContentValues values = new android.content.ContentValues();

        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DIRECTION, direction);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.JID, JID);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.MESSAGE, message);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DELIVERY_STATUS, delivery_status);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DATE, ts);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.PACKET_ID, packetID);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.GROUP_CHAT_SENDER_NAME, group_chat_sender_name);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.GROUP_CHAT_SENDER_PHONE, group_chat_sender_ph_no);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.MEDIA_TYPE, media_type);
        values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.IS_UPLOAD, -1);
      /*  if (media_type.equalsIgnoreCase("text"))
            values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.MEDIA_URL, "N/A");
        else {
            JSONObject mJSONObject = null;
            try {
                mJSONObject = new JSONObject(message);
                values.put(ChatProvider.ChatConstants.MEDIA_URL, mJSONObject.optString("media_url"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
*/

        mContentResolver.update(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, ChatProvider.ChatConstants.JID +"="+JID+" and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.GROUP_CHAT_SENDER_NAME+"="+group_chat_sender_ph_no+" and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DATE+"="+ts, null);
        //mContentResolver.insert(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

Please suggest any solution regarding the same.

Thanks to all.

Comment: `.. WHERE jid=amit@chat.spectratech.in and ...`

Answer (score 0):

add quotes to strings ''

```
 mContentResolver.update(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, ChatProvider.ChatConstants.JID +"= '"+JID+"' and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.GROUP_CHAT_SENDER_NAME+"= '"+group_chat_sender_ph_no+"' and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DATE+"= '"+ts+"'", new String[]{/*add selection args*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

put `JID` and `group_chat_sender_ph_no` in single quotation.

```
mContentResolver.update(ChatProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, ChatProvider.ChatConstants.JID +"='"+JID+"' and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.GROUP_CHAT_SENDER_NAME+"='"+group_chat_sender_ph_no+"' and "+ChatProvider.ChatConstants.DATE+"="+ts, null);
```